# My own taskbar for Win CE

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-ce

I've created WinCE 6.0 image without taskbar. So all app's maximized to full screen.
I want create my own app like taskbar. I want add only few buttons to this taskbar. But I want That other app in their maximized mode don't hide this task bar. And I don't want make my all top most, because they hide some part of other app.
How can I make my app like task bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify the existing taskbar in the current Explore shell (source at `%WINCEROOT%\PUBLIC\SHELL\OAK\HPC\EXPLORER\TASKBAR\taskbar.cpp` or is that's not flexible enough, you could [create your own Shell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446914.aspx) and create your own "taskbar-like" behavior however you'd like.

In either case, remember to **clone the code** to your own BSP tree! Don't modify the public tree.

Comment: I don't want modify existing task bar. I want create my own app with height 32px(and without form header and buttons like maximize and close) and add to this form few buttons. This app will be run like shell and placed on bottom screen. Other apps(not my) must maximize before my app bar. For example if screen height 300px, my app 32px other apps must have height 268px. I don't know How can I do this.

Answer (score 1):

The approach I've taken and works is to write a custom kiosk shell based on the explorer.exe code built in visual studio.  You could use platform builder as well, kind of the same tool now a days.  Looking back I'd say it was a bit heavy handed and it took a little bit of refactoring to CTaskBar and explorer to subclass CTaskBar to our needs, but it produced a shell that we could lock and unlock with complete explorer capabilities.  Perhaps a lighterweight approach would be to register your app's window as the taskbar (sorry the system call escapes me) and handle the taskbar specific messages in your winproc?

Comment: As I understand I can register my app as taskbar but how can I do this? Where I can get info about this?

Comment: As a start see WINCEXXX\PUBLIC\COMMON\OAK\INC\pwinuser.h, BOOL WINAPI RegisterTaskBar (HWND hwndTaskbar), but there are probably other calls dealing with the desktop that you'll need to take care of as well.  What version of CE is this for?

Comment: I use WinCe 6.0 R3 and I steel search way to solve this task.